# Finding same IDs in a certain amount of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a program that cycles through all .xml it can find in directory. It searches for device id and then adds all of them into a dictionary(i think) When I print it out it looks like

```
{'1.xml': [], '2.xml': []}
```

Next I insert the device IDs i get from the files into them so the output looks like :

```
{'1.xml': ['3', '12'], '2.xml': ['23', '3'']}
```

I'd like to get what device ids are the same so it prints out:

```
3
```

Maybe its possible to even display from what files it got the info, but that doesn't matter too much

Comment: len() of what list? Do you have a list of xml files? List of dicts?

Comment: @Jokab len() of the amount of xml files

Comment: @Jan check out the updated answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you so much, it solved everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### After you clarified your data

You can write a loop or use reduce, which you will have to import from `functools` if you are on python 3. You can use a lambda if you want, e.g. `lambda s1,s2: s1 & s2` but I prefer to import the appropriate operator from the `operator` module.

```
In [1]: some_dict = {'1.xml': ['3', '12'], '2.xml': ['23', '3']}

In [2]: from functools import reduce

In [3]: from operator import and_

In [4]: reduce(and_,map(set, some_dict.values()))

Out[4]: {'3'}
```

Equivalent for-loop would work like this:

```
In [8]: it = iter(some_dict.values())

In [9]: intersection = set(next(it))

In [10]: for vals in it:
    ...:     intersection &= set(vals)
    ...:     

In [11]: intersection
Out[11]: {'3'}
```

Comment: Hmm, I ran it, but it takes the wrong one: 
{'1.xml': ['3', '12'], '2.xml': ['23', '3'']} this is the input my dictionary outputs. When I printed out reduce(and_, map(set, listForListNames)
Output I get is {'.', ' x ', ' m ', ' l '} It does correct thing but in the wrong place. If it out puted {'3'} it would be great.

Comment: @Jan Wait, I thought you had a list of dictionaries.

Comment: isn't {'1.xml': [], '2.xml': []} a dictonary? I add the device id's i get into the    [ ]. And thats what i need to compare. Sorry if my wording is confusing, I am not sure about the termins

Comment: @Jan You mentioned you had a list and you wanted to find the same IDs from all the dictionaries. You gave as an example `set(dict1) & set(dict2)`. Update your question with an example of your data. I have a solution for you, but the question should reflect the correct problem

Comment: Last question, now it finds similar id that appears in all of the files, Is there a quick fix that if the ID appears in 1st and 5th file only, then it displays it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of the eval function. How about putting the dictionaries into an array and generating your code dynamically.

For example like:

```
list = [dict1]
list.append(dict2)  # append all dicts to the list

for i in range(len(list)):
    if i == len(list) - 1:
        string_code += "set(dict%d)" % (i+1)
    else:
        string_code += "set(dict%d) & " % (i+1)

difference = eval(string_code)
```

Just a first idea...

Comment: The question was updated. OP is not working with multiple dictionaries, but a single dictionary with lists as values.

Comment: Problem is if i need to go though 500 files. There will be lots of manual work here with that :/ At least how I understand that code

Comment: There is no need to use the `eval` function here. If you are using `eval`, that is a huge red-flag that there are probably better ways of accomplishing whatever it is you are trying to do.